# Why do source and sink have to be distinct in Ford-Fulkerson?

Tags: algorithms, network-flow, max-flow

Recently I have been studying the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm for determining max flow. I do not see why it is not allowed to have the source vertex be the same as the sink vertex. From what I have heard, doing this allows infinite flow. However if you take a graph where the source (which equals the sink) has no arcs leading into it shouldn't the max flow be $0$?

Answer (score 1):

In a flow network, the source and sink are "special".  The source is *defined* to have infinite incoming capacity, and the sink is defined to have infinite outgoing capacity -- they are different from all the other networks.  For any node with no incoming edges *other than the source*, it's true that the flow through that node has to be zero -- but the source is different, because it is special.

Why can't the source and sink be the same node?  Basically, because then you get a different problem with different characteristics.  That other problem is called [the circulation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulation_problem), and there are algorithms for it.  They are a bit different, though, and your teacher probably doesn't want to confuse you by adding unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

In the Maximum Flow problem at first step you assume that source has $\infty$ capacity, if it had limited capacity you would denote that by auxiliary arc to node.
Then you cut it to comply with constraints - weighted edges gives capacity. Since there are no arcs with weights -> there are no limits, what you put in source is immediately in the sink.
Otherwise if source had $0$ capacity then there would be no flow at all.